# Java AmazonS3Client getObject hanging, thread state stuck in IN_NATIVE during socketRead0

Tags: java, sockets, amazon-s3

I have a Java application which runs a series of parallel threads that download chunks of objects from AmazonS3. I noticed, after running for a few hours without any issues, eventually getting a specific chunk will hang and cause the program to freeze.

The Java process is still running, but CPU usage and network IO are minimal. Doing a thread dump, there is one thread that is never leaving the IN_NATIVE state and socketRead0() seems to never return during an SSL handshake. Here is the paraphrased stack trace:

```
Thread 17260: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=8, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=79, line=170 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=141 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(java.io.InputStream, byte[], int, int) @bci=21, line=465 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream) @bci=32, line=503 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(sun.security.ssl.InputRecord, boolean) @bci=44, line=973 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake() @bci=84, line=1375 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(boolean) @bci=13, line=1403 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake() @bci=2, line=1387 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(int, java.net.Socket, org.apache.http.HttpHost, java.net.InetSocketAddress, java.net.InetSocketAddress, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=87, line=533 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.net.InetSocketAddress, java.net.InetSocketAddress, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams) @bci=69, line=401 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.net.InetSocketAddress, java.net.InetSocketAddress, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams) @bci=60, line=128 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection, org.apache.http.HttpHost, java.net.InetAddress, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams) @bci=226, line=177 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams) @bci=126, line=304 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(org.apache.http.impl.client.RoutedRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=50, line=610 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost, org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=389, line=445 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(org.apache.http.HttpHost, org.apache.http.HttpRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=365, line=863 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=14, line=82 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest, org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext) @bci=3, line=57 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(com.amazonaws.Request, com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponseHandler, com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponseHandler, com.amazonaws.http.ExecutionContext, com.amazonaws.util.AWSRequestMetrics, com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$ExecOneRequestParams) @bci=369, line=728 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(com.amazonaws.Request, com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponseHandler, com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponseHandler, com.amazonaws.http.ExecutionContext) @bci=312, line=489 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(com.amazonaws.Request, com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponseHandler, com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponseHandler, com.amazonaws.http.ExecutionContext) @bci=150, line=310 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(com.amazonaws.Request, com.amazonaws.http.HttpResponseHandler, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) @bci=168, line=3796 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest) @bci=235, line=1201 (Compiled frame)
...
```

And here is a code snippet for how this is being executed:

```
protected static byte[] getChunk(AmazonS3Client client, long start, int offset, String bucket, String key) {
    if(offset < 1){
        return null;
    }
    S3Object obj = null;
    S3ObjectInputStream is = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[offset];

    try {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key);
        request.setRange(start, start + offset);

        obj = client.getObject(request);
        is = obj.getObjectContent();
        int copied = 0;
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer,copied,offset-copied)) > 0){
            copied += length;
        }

        buffer = (copied < 1) ? null : Arrays.copyOf(buffer, copied);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        buffer = null;
    } finally {
        Util.close(is);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

As a side note, in case this can be resolved with a different AmazonS3Client configuration, here is how the client is instantiated:

```
private static final String S3_ENDPOINT = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/";

public static AmazonS3Client getAmazonClient(String accessKey, String secretKey){
    AmazonS3Client client = null;
    try {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfig.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

        client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfig);
        client.setEndpoint(S3_ENDPOINT);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        client = null;
    }
    return client;
}
```

(This is also with aws-java-sdk version 1.10.9). Here are the JVM specs:

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas how to overcome this hang on the socket initialization?

Answer (score 0):

From your code,
I can see this

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
```

ClientConfiguration comes with a lot of options.

Maybe you could use this:

```
setSocketTimeout
```

and set it to maybe 5000. 
as per the documentation:

> Sets the amount of time to wait (in milliseconds) for data to be transfered over an established, open connection before the connection times out and is closed. A value of 0 means infinity, and isn't recommended.

the default value for `DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT` is 0.

ref:

[DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)

[setSocketTimeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setSocketTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks! So I did try explicitly setting all the different timeout options available from the documentation and the problem still occurs. Investigating further, it seems like potentially this is an edge case bug with the Java standard network library on my machine's setup. Another user had experienced the same difficulty here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049846 . As a very hacky and unsafe workaround, I was able to attach the GDB to the Java process running and manually closing socket by file descriptor and then the download would fail but the application would then resume.